# In CUDA kernels, __assume() or __builtin_assume()?

Tags: optimization, cuda, branch-prediction

CUDA offers the kernel author two functions, [`__builtin_assume()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#__builtin_assume) and [`__assume()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#__assume). Their signatures are the same:

```
void __builtin_assume(bool exp);
void __assume(bool exp);
```

and so is their one-line documentation. Are they the same? Is one of them deprecated?

Answer (score 3):

The difference is mentioned in a blog post: https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/boosting-productivity-and-performance-with-the-nvidia-cuda-11-2-c-compiler/

> NVCC also supports a similar built-in function, __assume(bool), when using cl.exe as a host compiler.

Comment: Why is there different syntax for cl.exe and other compilers? It's not as though `__builtin_assume` is even a GCC builtin, according to the link?